# What kind of BLDC motor is this?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, brushless-dc-motor

I pulled this motor from an actuator. I know it is BLDC based on the circuit-board, but I am not sure if it is a three pole or something else.

[image]

Comment: That's neat. Looks like each phase only has one electromagnet coil with an opposite coil on the other side. It looks like there is enough space for them too so cost cutting measure?

Comment: is this considered to be a 3 pole motor or what is it called?

Comment: I guess so but unsure if you count the coils or the magnets.

Comment: In a BLDC (and I am not 100 percent sure this is a BLDC) the number of poles is based on the number of magnetic poles in the rotor. So the way to determine how many poles a BLDC has is to count the magnets, one way or another. If you remove the rotor be advised that they snap into place with a great deal of magnetic force. So be careful not to pinch yourself. I am wondering if this could possibly be a switched reluctance motor. It definitely is not like any motor I have seen before.

Comment: Don't forget the iron plays a critical role in the performance of the motor. The coils just provide the magnetic potential that the steel carries/directs/funnels to the rotor. The gaps in the steel are **very** intentional and (probably) act like 9 sets of coils distributed around the stator.

Answer (score 5):

Your motor looks very similar to the one in [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-novel-linear-actuator-using-a-low-cost-BLDC-motor-Frachon-Foucaut/6697af10303b423ca0796725f752ae782033459c) which is described as a stepper motor:-

Fig. 9 : View of a MMT’s stepper motor and the gear box
[image]

Fig. 1 : Typical 3D view of an MMT permanent-magnet motor with 5 pole pairs, 3 coils... The blue and orange regions of the permanent magnet represent poles of opposite polarity.
[image]

These motors (made by [Moving Magnet Technologies](https://www.movingmagnet.com/en)) have 5 magnet pole pairs, which makes them '10 pole' motors (Note that *brushed* motors are often designated by the number of armature poles rather than magnet poles. A '3 pole' brushed motor typically has only two magnet poles).

This particular design can be used in stepper mode with open loop control, or BLDC mode using Hall sensors for position feedback. [Here's another paper](https://docplayer.net/52566729-Compact-bldc-stepper-motor-technology-for-ultra-slim-actuators.html) with more information about it.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but there is no such thing as a 3 pole motor. Motors are only designed with even numbers of poles (representing the number of magnets). You may come across the term pole-pairs, which is the number of (north facing magnets + south facing magnets)/2. Regardless of which type of motor this is, it is definitely interesting. The stator geometry is such that the flux paths on the stator magnetically isolate each coil from the other. I am assuming this is done because the motor has more than two poles (1 pole-pair). Hence the flux-linkage varies over a smaller angle than 180 mechanical degrees.

One idea to identify the number of poles would be to take another magnet and hold it some distance from the rotor. Rotate the rotor and feel the number of times the magnet is attracted and repelled for one rotation. Add the number of times the magnet is attracted to get the number of pole pairs.

Comment: Do you think it could be a switched reluctance motor?

Comment: I ruled that out based on RGB Engineer saying that it was a BLDC motor. The easiest test would be to pull the rotor out of the stator. The amount of force needed to pull it out would be a good indicator if it has magnets.

Comment: Sometimes questions on this exchange contain incorrect assumptions. The fact that the OP wonders if this could be a 3-pole motor could be an indication that the OP is not well-versed in motors. So I made the conjecture that perhaps the OP mis-categorized the motor. I did not intend to be rude, but maybe that was rude of me.

Comment: I did pull the rotor out of the stator, and there are definitely permanent magnets present.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a 3-phase, 9-slot, 8-pole BLDC motor.

[image]